# How to get Saxon to output un-escaped CDATA section

Tags: c#, xml, saxon

How can I get Saxon to convert a CDATA string into an XdmNode without escaping the < & > ?

Here is my 'ToXdmNode' function:

```
        Processor processor = xxx.GetProcessor();
        var builder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();

        builder.BaseUri = xxx.BaseUri;
        var tr = new StringReader("<stuff><![CDATA[<blah>]]></stuff>");
        var node = builder.Build(tr);
```

This code converts

```
<stuff><![CDATA[<blah>]]></stuff>
```

into an XdmNode that looks like:

```
<stuff>&lt;blah&gt;</stuff>
```

This causes problems later on when I send the OuterXml onto the next step.

How can I get my XdmNode to be unescaped?

Answer (score 1):

You say the code converts

```
<stuff><![CDATA[<blah>]]></stuff>
```

into an XdmNode that looks like:

```
<stuff>&lt;blah&gt;</stuff>
```

but actually that's not a conversion: the two things are just different serializations of the same content.

If you want to create the non-well-formed string

```
<stuff><blah></stuff>
```

then that's tricky using XSLT, because not being XML, this isn't the serialization of any valid XDM node. However, you can contrive it with the help of `disable-output-escaping`. For example the transformation

```
<xsl:template match="stuff">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

will produce this output provided that you send the transformation output to a Serializer (and not, for example, to an XdmNode).

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the serialiser we are using.  If the output from the transform uses the Saxon *Serializer* class, then the string is correct.  If the transform outputs to an XdmNode, and then subsequently serialises using the .net *XmlWriter* serialiser, then I get the issue described above.

Comment: Absolutely. That's why disable-output-escaping is deprecated; it can only be made to work if there is very close coupling between the XSLT transformation engine and the serializer.

Comment: So, you are saying, if I serialise during a transform it works, but if I serialise the output later, it doesn't work?

Comment: Correct, you need to serialize using the serializer that is aware of the "disable-output-escaping" directive. This represents a covert channel between the transformer and the serializer. The transformer is passing more than a result tree to the serializer, it's also passing instructions that says "disable escaping here" and "re-enable escaping here".